# Trying to get and set array data inside an object

Tags: drupal-8

I'm trying to extract (and set) from the screenshot below the ***conf->folders*** inside ***profile*** array. I am able to access other things such as "id" using $profile->id(). I tried what was suggested in other SO questions " $profile->conf['folders'] " which fails.

```
$folders = array();
$some_settings = \Drupal::config('some.settings');
foreach ($ids as id) {
    $profile = $storage->load($some_settings[$id]);
    $folders[] = $profile->conf['folders']; // Fails to get array
}
```

When finished want to reset the value to something (much like this):

```
$profile->conf['folders'] = $folders;
```

[image]

Comment: you should `$profile->conf()['folders'];` to get the folders, although to set the folders, you cannot do it from here, you will need setter method on the class, this also depends on the framework you're using

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have figured it out, I am new to Drupal programming but it seems I can do the following:

```
$folders = array();
$some_settings = \Drupal::config('some.settings');
foreach ($ids as id) {
    $profile = $storage->load($some_settings[$id]);
    $folders[] = $p->get('conf')['folders'];
}
// In following, $profile->set('conf.folders', $folders); should have worked instead, instead resigned 'conf' instead of just 'folders'.
$conf = $profile->get('conf');
$conf["folders"] = $folders;
$profile->set('conf', $conf);
```

Parsed from documents such as this:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/working-with-the-entity-api